# bash: $? != function return value?

Tags: linux, bash, return-value

Return values in bash functions are a popular topic, but I have not seen an answer that explains the behavior I'm seeing.

I have a bash function library "pt2026_firmware", including a function "pt2026_start_firmware" that explicitly returns 0 for success, 1 for failure. When I run

`bash -x -c "source pt2026_firmware; pt2026_start_firmware; echo $?"`

I get:

```
+ source pt2026_firmware
[...stuff deleted...]
+ '[' 0 -eq 0 ']'
+ return 1
+ echo 0
0
```

I'm obviously missing something very basic, but I don't understand why I'm getting $?=0 when I "return 1"? Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: What do you think happens to `$?` inside `" $? "`  doublequotes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want `$?` to be expanded *after* `pt2026_start_firmware` runs, you need to use single quotes around your code:

```
bash -x -c 'source pt2026_firmware; pt2026_start_firmware; echo $?'
```

Otherwise, the `echo $?` is changed to `echo 0` **before your new copy of `bash` even starts**.

Comment: Thanks so much; I figured it was something stupid.